# Easiest way to get a clojurescript REPL

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, clojurescript

What's the fastest way to get a clojurescript REPL up and running in the terminal? I don't need connection to a browser, just the REPL to evaluate expressions.

The docs seem to assume either that you want browser synchronization or give complicated acrobatics to get a simple REPL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the recently published [clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start guide](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start). It is really the most barebones and simple it has ever been.

Basically (and assuming you have java 8 and node.js installed):

1. Download the latest jar from here https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/releases/ and put it in a folder
2. Using instructions from here https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#nodejs-repl as inspiration:
3. Create `node_repl.clj` where you have the jar file with this contents:

   ```
   (require 'cljs.repl)
   (require 'cljs.repl.node)

   (cljs.repl/repl (cljs.repl.node/repl-env))
   ```
4. Execute with `java -cp cljs.jar clojure.main node_repl.clj`. This should open the repl, like this:

   ```
   $ java -cp cljs.jar clojure.main node_repl.clj
   ClojureScript Node.js REPL server listening on 50658
   To quit, type: :cljs/quit
   ClojureScript:cljs.user> (+ 1 2)
   3
   ```

If you want a fancier repl use `rlwrap` as stated on the guide (`rlwrap java -cp cljs.jar clojure.main node_repl.clj`)

And again, have a look at that Quick Start guide, it is really awesome (thanks Swannodette)

---

**Edit**

You can also get a working repl without node.js if you want too by using either nashorn (java 8 js vm) or rhino (older java-based js vm), substitute steps 3 and 4 with this ones:

**For Nashorn**

3. Create `nashorn_repl.clj` where you have the jar file with this contents:

   ```
   (require 'cljs.repl)
   (require 'cljs.repl.nashorn)

   (cljs.repl/repl (cljs.repl.nashorn/repl-env))
   ```
4. Execute with `java -cp cljs.jar clojure.main nashorn_repl.clj`. This should open the repl, like this:

   ```
   $ java -cp cljs.jar clojure.main nashorn_repl.clj
   To quit, type: :cljs/quit
   ClojureScript:cljs.user> (+ 1 2)
   3
   ```

**For Rhino**

3. Create `rhino_repl.clj` where you have the jar file with this contents:

   ```
   (require 'cljs.repl)
   (require 'cljs.repl.rhino)

   (cljs.repl/repl (cljs.repl.rhino/repl-env))
   ```
4. Execute with `java -cp cljs.jar clojure.main rhino_repl.clj`. This should open the repl, like this:

   ```
   $ java -cp cljs.jar clojure.main rhino_repl.clj
   To quit, type: :cljs/quit
   ClojureScript:cljs.user> (+ 1 2)
   3
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the time you put on your explanation, it is very clear. Unfortunately, these steps alone don't sem to be enough: I am getting a 

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate cljs/repl'__init.class or cljs/repl'.clj on classpath: , compiling:(/Users/sergi/lib/node_repl.clj:1:1)` error.

Comment: Solved now. The quickstart tutorial had a typo in the code: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojurescript/tV26-cGIXrA

Comment: Great :) Quoting is confusing at the beginning !